# GraphQL: How to structure mutation to add an item to a list of ints?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, graphcool

I am using graph.cool and Apollo. This is a simplified schema below. I want to add an int to the list and compute a new average.

GraphQL Schema for a Test model. How would I add another int to the list property?

```
type Test @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  list: [Int!]
  average: Int
}
```

Comment: I don’t think you can do that with graph.cool. You can read back the entire list, then append in a mutation.

Comment: Another work around is to create a mutation server-less function and due it inside there